# Error launching emulator android avd

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm done with virtualization on bios, installing the emulator accelerator on my SDK; however, when I try to install intelhaxm-android.exe I got the below message. I'm using AMD.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can't install Intel HAXM on a computer with an AMD processor.

Comment: @Shawn Use a computer with an Intel processor. Or use the emulator without HAXM (i.e. the ARM, rather than x86 system images), which is slower. Or use a third-party emulator product, such as Genymotion.